# Maximize button not resizing fieldset size

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a field set which is loaded with child content. I have set the height and min height of the field set dynamically based on window.height().

When i open the application the window size is minimized. When i maximize the window. the field set height doesn't change.

Could you please help with that. Below is the code.

```
<fieldset class="step-3 body" id="wizard-p-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wizard-h-2" style="left: -930px; width:100%; overflow-y: auto">
                                        <div id="alert">My Alert</div>
                                        @RenderBody()
                                    </fieldset>
```

the java script used to set the height and min-height

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("fieldset").css("min-height", ($(window).height() - 200));
    $("fieldset").css("height", ($(window).height() - $(window).height()*0.3))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 $("fieldset").css("min-height", ($(window).height() - 200));
 $("fieldset").css("height", ($(window).height() - $(window).height()*0.3))
});
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your help.